# How to simulate acceleration using Corona sdk's transitions

Tags: coronasdk, transition, acceleration

Working on a little game with clouds moving in the background. I'm using a runtime listener that upon touching, will make the clouds travel faster. This is done using the transition.to method within Corona sdk.

The problem with this is that the transition happens instantly. This is jarring and unrealistic. I'm exploring ways to make it so that the cloud naturally eases into different transition speeds, or in other words, for the cloud to accelerate/decelerate. I imagine this is possible using the physics engine, but what about only using transition methods?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into easings.  These change the default behavior of the transition instead of being linear, you can have it start slow and speed up, etc.  See:  https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/easing/index.html